# Derivation of formula to calculate the angle of inclination

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-explanation

I understand that in order to find the angle between two lines, you can calculate the angle of inclination of each of the lines and take the difference between those two. However, I'm not sure exactly why the formula to calculate the angle of inclination is what it is. I'd love it if someone can provide a simple, intuitive explanation for that. Assume I know basic high school calculus? Thanks! Here's the formula I'm talking about:

$θ=\tan^{−1}m$

Comment: It would help if you showed us the formula that you want explained.

Comment: @stevengregory Hi I've edited the question to include it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the definition of $m$.  It is the rise over the run.  Then we have $\tan \theta = \frac m1$ by the definition of tangent.  They are just inverting this.
[image]

Comment: The figure is rather confusing, to be honest. I suggest changing the text a bit, to "Then we have $\tan \theta = m = \frac{a}{c}$ by the definition of tangent, with $a$ corresponding to rise and $c$ run."  and removing $1$ and $m$ from the illustration.

Comment: @NominalAnimal:  I wanted to use $m$ like OP did.  Unfortunately I find it hard to get Geogebra to give me a larger horizontal scale so that the horizontal leg could be $1$.  Your description may well help.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think $m$ is necessary in the image. If you just want to omit $1$ and $m$ in it, I edited it for you: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsDDw.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsDDw.png).

Comment: It seems easy enough to get a larger horizontal scale by clicking on the "+" magnifying-glass icon. The thing I do not know is how to stop GeoGebra from inserting many other numbers between 0 and 1 when one does this.